# Decorator pattern: how can I call(back) some members of decorator wrappers from the core class

Tags: c++, callback, decorator

I am implementing a decorator pattern following the example in [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/cpp/1):

- Class `I`: is the interface class, common to both *core* class and *decorator base* class
- Class `A`: is the *core class*
- Class `D`: is the *decorator base* class
- Classes `X`, `Y`, `Z`: inherit from the *decorator base* class and extend functionality of the *core class* dynamically

There is one method in class `A` (`A::endTraining()`), which is triggered at the end of a timer variable (also present in class `A`). This method needs to call some member of `X`, `Y` and `Z` classes.
Is it possible? Is it good practice? How?

For example, is creating a mechanism to register the *pointers-to-`XYZ::endTraining`* in class `A` a correct approach?

(showing only relevant bits)

```
typedef void (D::*pCallback_fn)(void);

class I 
{
  public:
    virtual void endTraining() = 0;
    virtual void regTrainingCallbacks(pCallback_fn ptrFn) = 0;
};

class A: public I {
  public:

    void endTraining() {
        //do stuff
        //then do stuff in D (and its derivatives)
        //   by iterating through fnList
    }
    void regTrainingCallbacks(pCallback_fn ptrFn) 
    { 
        fnList.push_back( ptrFn ); 
    }
  private:
    std::list<pCallback_fn> fnList;
};

class D: public I {
  public:
    D(I *inner) {
        m_wrappee = inner;
    }
    void regTrainingCallbacks(pCallback_fn ptrFn) 
    { 
        m_wrappee->regTrainingCallbacks(ptrFn); 
    }
  private:
    I *m_wrappee;
};

class X /*,Y,Z*/ : public D {
  public:
    X(I *core): D(core)
    {
        D::regTrainingCallbacks( this->*endTraining() ); //
    }
  private:
    void endTraining(){
      //do stuff when called by A::endTraining() through D
    }
};
```

What can be done instead?

Comment: You also need an object `D` to call the methods registered in `fnList`. In fact, you could register in class `A` all decorators by adding another virtual method `virtual void regDecorator(D* decorator)` that would be called by the constructor of `D`. This method would be implemented in A by the registration in a field besides `fnList`. Then `A::endTraining` could call all the call-back methods of `fnList` on all the decorators. It might be different if you only want to notify `X` decorators or the `X` that has registered the call-back.

Comment: Why don't you use a list of `std::function`s instead of a list of pointers to member methods?

Comment: @Franck `regDecorator` seems a good idea , but then I must check if XYZ all have an "endTraining()` method. I'm looking into info about how to do that but cannot find any. Is it as simple as testing for `null`?

Comment: @skypjack if I end up not passing the decorator itself, then I will :)

Comment: In fact, you can only register the decorators that have the `endTraining` method if the call to `regDecorator` is in the `X` constructor. The solution of skypjack is that since it can associate the call-back function to the object by calling something like `D::regTrainingCallBacks(std::bind(&X::endTraining, this))`.

Comment: @Franck so you mean that yours and skypjacks answers are not mutually exclusive? could you elaborate on it abit in an answer (as what you proposed is closer to what I am implementing) ? thank you

Comment: @nass My first answer was to have two fields in the core class `A`: `std::list<pCallback_fn> fnList` and `std::list<D*> decoratorList`. The decorator pattern suggests that both lists are in connection, so you can have `std::list<std::pair<pCallback_fn, D*> > fnBindList`. I think a list of `std::list<std::function>` exactly carries the same information and also provides the ability to store extra args.

Comment: @nass Is the `I` interface under your control or is it defined by a library that cannot be changed? (as you describe the problem, it looks like the `I` interface would accept a single callback - with a defined signature - and you want to "multiplex" it).

Comment: @Franck I understand now what you meant. Still I fail to see why I need to register both `pCallback_fn` and `D*`. Isn't either enough for me to call the `XYZ::endTraining()` method?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi indeed `I` is under my control. But I am not sure what you are trying to point out.

Comment: @nass The question is quite unclear on why do you need the decorator. Trying to avoid a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. For example: your "Isn't either enough for me to call the XYZ::endTraining() method? " seems to indicate that you are insensitive to what `this` D has (if you aren't sensitive, why do you need a D at all, wouldn't a static method calling into XYZ as statics be suficient?)

Comment: @nass Yes, I know, SO requires you to stick with MVCE, so you are required to provide you "This is how I'm trying to do it" and let the "This is why I'm trying to do it" as a secondary concern.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi. ok the reason for decorator is related to fact that I want dynamic functionality which I would otherwise have to define in several derived classes. As for the statics, yes I could declare them as such. should I necessarily though? Does it offer something more than having pointer-to-functions instead of pointer  to member functions?

Comment: @nass In fact, you cannot call `XYZ::endTraining()` without any object since it is not a static method. Storing a `D*` or a `X*` or a closure with your method provides you the object you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing one fault in the original design, in which the 'trainer' (the entity registering training callbacks) must be a callback in itself (is there any reason the notifier - former class `A` - must be a callback itself?).

I changed the class names to put into evidence their responsibilities.

The `MainTrainingProcess` replaces the original `class A` (instances of which would have been wrapped by `D`-es) and the `D` itself.

```
class EndTrainingListener
{
public:
  virtual ~EndTrainingListener() { }

  virtual void endTraining()=0;
};

class ITrainingProcess
{
public:
  virtual ~ITrainingProcess() { }
  virtual void regTrainingCallbacks(EndTrainingListener* callback) = 0;
};

class MainTrainingProcess : public ITrainingProcess {
public:
  virtual ~MainTrainingProcess() {
    // destroy other resources used during training
  }

  virtual void regTrainingCallbacks(EndTrainingListener* callback) {
    this->listeners.push_back(callback);
  }

  void train() {
    // do training stuff
    // ...
    // do my specific actions at the end of training
    // ...

    // finish by notifying all listeners
    this->atEndTraining();
  }
protected:
  void atEndTraining() {
    for(auto l : this->listeners) {
      l->endTraining();
    }
  }

  std::list<EndTrainingListener*> listeners;
};

class X /*Y, Z*/ : public EndTrainingListener {
public:
  virtual ~X();

  virtual void endTraining() {
    // do specific stuff
  }
};
```